# ComponentResourceKey cannot be resolved when defining more than one

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have defined 3 styles in ResourceDictionary in external assembly like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:Common},
ResourceId=numbersOnly}" TargetType="TextBox">
...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:Common},
ResourceId=positiveInt}" TargetType="TextBox">
...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:Common},
ResourceId=positiveDecimal}" TargetType="TextBox">
...
</Style>
```

In the same assembly I have defined a class like this:

```
public static class Common {
        public static ComponentResourceKey NumbersOnly {
            get {
                return new ComponentResourceKey(
                typeof(Common), "numbersOnly");
            }
        }
        public static ComponentResourceKey PositiveInt {
            get {
                return new ComponentResourceKey(
                typeof(Common), "positiveInt");
            }
        }
        public static ComponentResourceKey PositiveDecimal {
            get {
                return new ComponentResourceKey(
                typeof(Common), "positiveDecimal");
            }
        }
    }
```

I use those styles like this:

```
<TextBox Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static segres:Common.NumbersOnly}}" />
```

This works if I define only one property in the class above, but if I define more than one (like above) resource cannot be resolved.

Why is this happening? This behaviour does not seem logical to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in WPF with external dictionaries.  It occurred in 3.5 and carried over to 4.0.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553528/defaultstylekey-style-not-found-in-inner-mergeddictionaries